# Render props with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a render props wrapper component. It is working, but I am getting type errors. Here is my link to a code sandbox as well. [link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-worker-l5odx5?file=/src/App.tsx:33-360)

1. the first error I am getting is children is an expression that is not callable.
2. the second error is "hello" has implicitly any type.

Looking for a react/typescript guru for help

```
type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};


const ControlledWrapper: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const state: { hello: string } = { hello: 'hello' };

  return children(state);
};



export default function App() {
  return (
    <ControlledWrapper>
    {({ hello }) => <div>{hello}</div>}
  </ControlledWrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the type of `children` to a function that returns a React element:

```
type Props = {
  children: (ctx: { hello: string }) => ReactElement;
};
```

Now when you use the component you get the right types:

```
    {({ hello }) => <div>{hello}</div>} // 'hello' is a string
```

Try this out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnOAXjgG9y440AFsAA2AEyIA7AFxwAFBgAeMrnAFJhwiDJYwowCQHM4AXwCUHAHyJiMAHTJ0MAKLCkIJBJgVjFcmggSOnAAwgG6EBpIogDqUChgdFAyDhi2AGLBADxMEKxWnLIqgiLiHibm7FY8fP6B8DooMEjKquqa2rr6RsYc3K0aWnAA5GoDQya+fEQwAK5QEvxCYpKyDU2m3r5ICpCwcKJImCgzwlgzEhjAAXAAggmy5tVw03MLsrx8cJmhnjiRMXEEkgoBYPnwuIV+ppypYvqJgAA3CxcUaaYyZAD08KRxg+mJ+4X+sXiiVBfA25GMQA).